# Why is a non-const reference to const allowed if first initialised with non-const?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

The compiler will, quite understandably, disallow the following:

```
const int ci = 1000;
int &r = ci;
```

because that would mean I could attempt to change the value of ci through r, but ci is const.

Why then is the following allowed, which is the same as above except for first assigning a non-const int to r?

```
int i;
const int ci = 1000;
int &r = i;
r = ci;
```

If you try to change ci through r, ci will remain the same value. Nevertheless, it is not caught by the compiler, unlike the first example. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Where would the only const in this, `ci`, somehow be compromised ?  `r` references `i`. The assignment doesn't change that. References aren't pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't rebinding `r` to reference `ci`. You're assigning the referencee of `r` (`i`) the value of `ci`.

Comment: D'oh that's right, I've only ever used references as function parameters, so I came to the wrong conclusion that you can change the object to which a reference is bound to. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

In your example `r` is created as a reference to `i`. So when you do this:

```
r = ci;
```

You assign the value of `ci` to `r` and thus to `i`. You are not changing the value of `ci`, so everything is fine.

EDIT: You cannot change which object a reference is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you explained it yourself:

> If you try to change ci through r, ci will remain the same value.

r (and by consequence, i) contain a copy of the value of ci, not a reference to ci (which is what you were doing in the first example). So the const nature of ci is not affected and the compiler allows it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
const int ci = 1000;
int &r = i;
r = ci;
```

The last line has exactly the same effect as

```
r = 1000;
```

You may try changing 1000 through `r` all day long but it will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword controls what you can do through that particular variable name. It does not ensure that the underlying data will never change.

So, for example, is is fairly common to have an object which has an internal state that it can modify freely, but to have that object hand out const references or pointers to its internals so that others can't manipulate them directly.